# Get element with certain ID using .is() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be very simple, but I just can't make it work.

I am trying to find an element with certain ID using .is() method:

http://jsfiddle.net/4hbvgwnv/

```
<div id="foo">Some text</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = "foo";
    alert( $("div").is("#" + id).text() );
}):
```

But this just won't work. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I know I can select an element with $("#foo"), but I want to use the .is() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** which filter elements based the selector. **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** will return a Boolean value not the jQuery object, returns true at least one element is matched else returns false.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = "foo";
  alert($("div").filter("#" + id).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Some text</div>
```

Instead you can simply use selector `$("div#" + id)` which select div with that particular id. It will only select element is div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = "foo";
  alert($("div#" + id).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/is/

.is() returns a boolean, if you check your developer console you got an error showing that "text" isn't valid ! 
Are you sure that .is() can be used for that intent ?

---

A solution that might work (kinda weird way to do it tho) : http://jsfiddle.net/4hbvgwnv/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var id = "foo";
   if($("div").is("#" + id))
      alert($("div").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`is()` returns a boolean, you should use `filter()` instead:

```
$("div").filter("#" + id).text()
```

That said, if you're searching by id, you don't need to bother with a parent selector at all:

```
$('#' + foo).text()
```